# What happened to Mo?

Tags: plot-explanation, marcella

Warning: This question has spoilers about the end of the season.

In season 1 episode 7 of the quite interesting series [Marcella](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5269594/) Mo goes on to confront and threat Marcella about the death of his brother Hassan.

Later during the episode she goes to work and continues the investigation, and in the next episode we see the conclusion of the investigation of the murders.

However it's never shown what happened between the beginning of Mo trying to extract a confession and the moment Marcella got free, and we don't see Mo ever again. Is it explained in the series where did he go or what happened to him?